# Keep considering an `has_many :through` Record Association as an ActiveRecord::Relation class after a iterative operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to keep the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class after doing this (in the below code `article_category_relationships` represents an `has_many :through` Record Association):

```
# @article.article_category_relationships.class               # => ActiveRecord::Relation
@article.article_category_relationships.map(&:category).class # => Array
```

It should be something like this:

```
@article.article_category_relationships.map(&:category).class # => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

It seems that the `map` method makes losing the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class.

**Is it possible to keep the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class after run an iterative method? If so how can do?**

*Note*: I would like that in order to keep using of all methods provided by Ruby on Rails for the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class (`.where(...)`, `.count`, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ruby 1.9, check out tap:

```
obj.tap{|x|...} => obj
Yields x to the block, and then returns x. The primary purpose of this method is to "tap into" a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

    (1..10)                .tap {|x| puts "original: #{x.inspect}"}
      .to_a                .tap {|x| puts "array: #{x.inspect}"}
      .select {|x| x%2==0} .tap {|x| puts "evens: #{x.inspect}"}
      .map { |x| x*x }     .tap {|x| puts "squares: #{x.inspect}"}
```